# linking in the laravel join function

Tags: laravel

I get data from two different tables with Join function. But the link code for the edit page does not work.

```html
index.blade.php file 

@foreach($data as $row)

   tr>
    <td>{{$row->customer_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$row->customer_phone}}</td>
    <td>{{$row->product_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$row->sale_date}}</td>
    <td>{{$row->delivery_date}}</td>
    <td>
       <a href="{{route('orders.create'),[$row['order_id']]}}">
       <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm fa fa-edit"></button></a>
    </td>
   </tr>

@endforeach
```

```html
web.php file

Route::group(['namespace'=>'orders', 'prefix'=>'orders', 'as'=>'orders.'], function (){
   Route::get('/', 'indexController@index')->name('index');
   Route::get('/create', 'indexController@create')->name('create');
   Route::post('/create/', 'indexController@store')->name('create.post');
   Route::get('/detail/{id}', 'indexController@show')->name('detail');
   Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'indexController@edit')->name('edit');
   Route::post('/edit/{id}', 'indexController@update')->name('edit.post');
});
```

```html
indexController.php file

 public function index()
    {
        $data = DB::table('orders')
            ->select('orders.customer_name', 'orders.customer_phone', 'products.product_name', 'orders.sale_date','orders.delivery_date')
            ->join('products', 'orders.product_id', '=', 'products.product_id')
            ->get();
        return view('orders.index', compact('data'));
    }
```

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\personality\resources\views\orders\index.blade.php)

Comment: and can you show some code?

Comment: I added my codes.

Answer (score 2):

You have an `stdClass` object, you can't get parameters from it using array syntax.

```
$object->parameter; // object
$array['element'];  // array
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be meaningless output outside of the `route` helper  function?

Comment: OP has this as href `{{ route('orders.create') , [$row['order_id'] ]  }}` so it'll just be `{{ route('orders.create'),  $row->order_id }}` look where the route parantheses is closed

Comment: that would definitely be an issue and what they have is malformed, though they are not getting a syntax error, just the trying to use an object as array error ... assuming that line they are showing is actually what is throwing the error ... one of those lovely, multiple issues in one line things :)

Comment: Those questions I want to pull my hair out

Comment: @Saly3301 hehe I hear ya  ...  one of those things were it is technically valid PHP (minus the object/array issue) just completely the wrong intent

Answer (score 2):

So instead of this:

```
$row['order_id']
```

Can you try this:

```
$row->order_id
```

Comment: ofcourse it did not, as you are using the array out of the `route()` helper function, that should go as a second parameter. Take a look at @Saly3301 answer. That's the one you should be using.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I tried the @Saly3301 suggested method. Didn't work in that method

Answer (score 1):

Pass the ID of a model as a second argument to route and access the attribute of a model (object) with the arrow operator

```html
<a href="{{ route('orders.create', $row->order_id) }}">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Fatih you should adjust your link to match this ... you can wrap the second argument in an array if you wish

Comment: We don't know what your routes look like so we can't be 100% sure ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Can someone help me?